# rabbitmq-server installation woes on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04, apt

I downloaded and installed `esl-erlang_16.a-rc1~ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb` then downloaded `rabbitmq-server_3.0.2-1_all.deb` and ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.0.2-1_all.deb
```

It resulted in the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-nox (>= 1:12.b.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Tried to install `erlang-nox`:

```
sudo apt-get install erlang-nox
```

It resulted in the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
erlang-nox : Depends: erlang-diameter but it is not going to be installed
```

From this point on, I tried to (manually) install the dependencies, every effort results in yet another unmet dependency, funny thing is the dependencies start to become cyclical (A needs B, B needs A).

Also tried to add the following

```
deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

and ran

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

same result.

Can anybody please shed some light?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When I install the Debian package, I get the same message, but run this afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The -f will automatically try to fix any missing dependencies.  You may need to `sudo apt-get update` first.  That could be causing some of your dependency issues.

Comment: I already tried that, sorry didn't mention in my original post, it results in: The following packages will be REMOVED:
  esl-erlang rabbitmq-server

Comment: Just curious, but does starting rabbitmq with esl erlang installed work, regardless of the supposed package conflict?

Comment: I gave up on rabbitmq (after several hours) and went with activemq instead.